# Taking picture with QTCaptureView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, image

Is it possible to simply take a picture and save it somewhere using a QTCaptureView and Apple's built-in iSight? I've seen lots of tutorials on recording video but none on simply taking a picture. Any help or guidance is appreciated!

- Collin

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with QTKit - the QTKit Application Programming Guide has a section for this titled, "[Creating a Single-Frame Grabbing Application](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008156-CH108-SW34)".

The better approach, however, is ImageKit's [PictureTaker](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/IKImagePicker/IKImagePicker.html). It gives you the standard UI found in ImageBooth and other apps and is dead-simple to use in code.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of [ImageSnap](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/macosx/imagesnap/) useful for understanding how to use QTKit to do this sort of thing. It is a simple command line application for taking pictures with the iSight camera.